# ¿Cómo usar una imagen como sprite en Unity?

Tags: unity3d

Tengo un panel al cual le quiero agregar una imagen de fondo, ya importé la imagen a mi proyecto pero cuando la arrastró sobre la propiedad del panel que se llama **Source Image** no me deja, también le di doble click a esta propiedad y se abre un menú que dice **select sprite** pero no aparece la imagen que quiero usar.

Comment: Has probado añadiendo UI image?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Tienes que modificar la imagen para que pueda ser usada para **2D y UI**. Para ello selecciona la imagen, en el inspector, en la propiedad **Texture Type** selecciona **Sprite**, da aplicar y ya puedes usar la imagen para lo que necesitas.